# feature names from sklearn pipeline: not fitted error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection, names

I'm working with scikit learn on a text classification experiment. Now I would like to get the names of the best performing, selected features. I tried some of the answers to similar questions, but nothing works. The last lines of code are an example of what I tried. For example when I print `feature_names`, I get this error: `sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This SelectKBest instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.`
Any solutions?

```
scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=False) 

enc = LabelEncoder()
y = enc.fit_transform(labels)

feat_sel = SelectKBest(mutual_info_classif, k=200)  
clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression()

pipe = Pipeline([('vectorizer', DictVectorizer()),
                 ('scaler', StandardScaler(with_mean=False)),
                 ('mutual_info', feat_sel),
                 ('logistregress', clf)])

feature_names = pipe.named_steps['mutual_info']
X.columns[features.transform(np.arange(len(X.columns)))]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to **fit the pipeline** and then call `feature_names`:

**Solution**

```
scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=False) 

enc = LabelEncoder()
y = enc.fit_transform(labels)

feat_sel = SelectKBest(mutual_info_classif, k=200)  
clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression()

pipe = Pipeline([('vectorizer', DictVectorizer()),
                 ('scaler', StandardScaler(with_mean=False)),
                 ('mutual_info', feat_sel),
                 ('logistregress', clf)])

# Now fit the pipeline using your data
pipe.fit(X, y)

#now can the pipe.named_steps
feature_names = pipe.named_steps['mutual_info']
X.columns[features.transform(np.arange(len(X.columns)))]
```

**General information**

From the documentation [example here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) you can see the

```
anova_svm.set_params(anova__k=10, svc__C=.1).fit(X, y)
```

This sets some initial parameters (k parameter for anova and C parameter for svc)

and then calls `fit(X,y)` to fit the pipeline.

**EDIT**:

for the new error, since your X is a list of dictionaries I see one way to call the columns method that you want. This can be done using pandas.

```
X= [{'age': 10, 'name': 'Tom'}, {'age': 5, 'name': 'Mark'}]

df = DataFrame(X) 
len(df.columns)
```

result:

```
2
```

Hope this helps

Comment: my instances (X) is a list of dictionaries. When I run the code, I still get an error at the last line: `list object has no attribute columns`.

Comment: @Bambi I edited my answer providing a possible solution for the new error.

Comment: thank you, this helps! I have just one question, is there a way to get the real feature names? Like 'age' and 'name' in your example?

Comment: @Bambi yes. in my second example you just need to use names = list(df). If the answer helped, you can mark it as accepted. cheers